# Why didn't Frieza know about Goku and Kid Buu's fight?

Tags: dragon-ball-super, dragon-ball-z

In *Dragon Ball Z*, when Goku was fighting Kid Buu, there were many enemies watching him from Hell.

From DBZ Wikia article on [Hell](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Hell):

> In the Kid Buu Saga, during the fight with Kid Buu, the ogres are seen watching the fight alongside Cell, Frieza, King Cold, Recoome, Burter, Jeice, Guldo, Dr. Gero, Appule, and Babidi.

However, when Frieza was revived, he didn't know about the fight with Majin Buu.

Is there any reason as to why this is so?

Comment: I'm not motivated enough to check, but I don't remember any of those hell-spectator scenes from the manga, so I'm assuming that it's anime filler.  Additionally, Toriama doesn't seem to concerned with what happened in the past anyway, so I wouldn't read too deep into that kind of stuff.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As stated in the Wikia article on [Hell](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Hell) (emphasis mine):

> Hell (Jigoku), or HFIL (Home For Infinite Losers in the edited English dub), is a place in Other World where evil characters (and sometimes, in the case of Piccolo, Goku, and Pikkon, protagonists) go after they die. **Hell is never actually shown in the original manga, but it is shown several times throughout various medias of Dragon Ball.**

Hence, it's an anime inconsistency which is not the fault of Akira Toriyama. One can only assume that the scene was not taken into account in *Dragon Ball Super* because they adapted it from the manga and didn't take into account the anime-added filler.

Answer (score 8):

Well it could be because of the wish made to Shenron to wipe out the memory of everyone about the incident of Majin Buu, this wish might have also wiped out the memories of the people in hell. So that's why Freiza doesn't remember.

Answer (score 3):

Frieza was tortured way too much in hell with those tiny cute creatures playing those drums which might have played with his memory and I do remember that after that fight, a wish was made to Shenron to erase the memory of people so no one remembers what happened on earth, or possibly it's an anime, anything can happen to make the story look better.

Answer (score 0):

I think its probably because of the fact that, when frieza ended up in hell (well before kid buu's time), the last "living memories" he had were goku an SSj and trunks blowing the living hell outta him. For him, as an alien "awake", dats the last set of memories he had. But once he is revived, the last thing he remembered was his death and before that. Dats why, when that underling tells him about beerus, he says his father always told him not to mess with the god of destruction. But at that time he didn't mention cell or buu.

Hence it seems like the lapse in memory because of death is what caused the question to even arise.

Comment: but he remembered his afterlife, and was quite mad at Goku for putting him through that torture. Also that torture did not included a TV to the outside world to watch what Goku was doing.

Comment: Was there a TV during the buu fight? it was there during the cell fight as far as i remember....but was it there during the buu fight?

Comment: IN the filler chunks (recall Hell is never shown in canon except possibly in Resurrection of F), during the buu fight, everyone in hell is watching, including cell and frieza. Even babbady (however you spell the name of that magic users who was the previous master of buu) was there, cheering for goku to kill buu, specifically because buu killed him (thanks to gokus temptations), but as i said, this was done by the animators only. Toriyama was the one making most of the story decisions for the movie, so he stuck to his origional work, where we never saw freiza again after mecha freiza.

Comment: ohhh....ya....correct.....